# How to Find and Output Regex Pattern between two strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to match all the times the a string starts with  and ends with  and then capture or print the value between the two ends, which would be in this case, 1112223333.

Here is my code so far that just prints none when I run it. I am relatively new to regex so all the help would be appreciated.:

```
string= "<x:a>1112223333</x:a>"
x = re.search(r"\<x:a/w+", str)
print(x)
```

I want the output to be:

```
'1112223333'
```

So another example, if the string was string= "3333333333", I would want the output to be

```
'3333333333'
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: `/w` is not the same as `\w`, and you're missing a `>` after matching the `a`, and you should probably be using an XML parser for something like this anyway. `<` doesn't need to be escaped either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you use a group, which is defined by parenthesis, in (\w+), and then your reffer to it by its number, as in x.group(1). if you had 2 groups, than you understand the analogy of numbering the groups...

```py
string= "<x:a>1112223333</x:a>"
import re
x = re.search(r"\<x:a\>(\w+)\<\/x:a\>", string)
print(x.group(1))
```